# Rails: Get Client IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client, ip-address

In Rails, what's the best way to get the ip address of the client connecting to the server?

Here are two ways I've found:

```
request.remote_ip
request.env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']
```

Answer (score 347, accepted):

I would just use the `request.remote_ip` that's simple and it works. Any reason you need another method?

See: [Get real IP address in local Rails development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887943/ip-address-in-rails)
for some other things you can do with client server ip's.

Answer (score 51):

`request.remote_ip` is an interpretation of all the available IP address information and it will make a best-guess. If you access the variables directly you assume responsibility for testing them in the correct precedence order. Proxies introduce a number of headers that create environment variables with different names.

Answer (score 11):

Get client ip using command:

```
request.remote_ip
```

Answer (score 4):

I found `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` very useful too in cases when `request.remote_ip` returns `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested and using a newer rails and the Devise gem: Devise's "trackable" option includes a column for current/last_sign_in_ip in the users table.