# How do I get a client's ip address in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function in my controller that calls another function form the model that needs to be fed the ip address

```
  def get_location_users
    if current_user
      return current_user.location_users
    else

      l = Location.find_by_ip(request.remote_ip)

      lu = LocationUser.new({:location_id => l.id, :radius => Setting.get("default_radius").to_i})
      return [lu]
    end
  end
```

from what I gathered remote.request_ip gives you the ip address, however when I call that function with request.remote_ip the object is nil. If I put in a static ip address though it produces the right output. What would be the correct way to get the ip address if remote.request_ip does not do so?

also when I try typing "request.remote_ip" in the console it returns "undefined local variable or method "request" from main"

Comment: Are you testing it in development or in production ? Also it is normal that it does not work on the rails console as the rails console does not respond to an http call so do not have a request object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: Get Client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465476/rails-get-client-ip-address)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like code that should be in a model, so I'm assuming that's where this method is. If so, you can't (at least 'out of the box') access the request object from your model as it originates from an HTTP request -- this is also why you get "undefined local variable or method "request" from main" in your console.

If this method is not already in your model I would place it there, then call it from you controller and pass in request.remote_ip as an argument.

```
def get_location_users(the_ip)
  if current_user
    return current_user.location_users
  else
    l = Location.find_by_ip(the_ip)
    lu = LocationUser.new({:location_id => l.id, :radius => Setting.get("default_radius").to_i})
    return [lu]
  end
end
```

Then, in your controller ::

```
SomeModel.get_location_users(request.remote_ip)
```

Also, be aware that "Location.find_by_ip" will return nil if no records are matched.

And, you can issue a request in your console by using **app.get "some-url"**, then you can access the request_ip from request object **app.request.remote_ip** and use it for testing if needed.

Comment: This is correct.  The `request` object is available only in the context of a request, meaning: the controllers and views.  It's not available in models (or mailers).  So you have to get the ip and pass it to a model method, as in this example.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a typo in your question or are you really calling remote.request_ip?

The correct method would be `request.remote_ip`

Answer (score 2):

- **HTTP requests:** `request.ip` (as sebastianh pointed out in his answer)

  also available as: `request.env['action_dispatch.request_id']`
- **HTTPS requests:** `request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].split(/,/).try(:first)`