# where does geocoded find a user's ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

To begin, sorry for the newbie question. I'm adding the geocoder gem to my app, and would like to query based on User ip_address. I've added latitude and longitude columns to the User database, but do I need to add ip_address to the User database as well? If so, is this a number or string or something else? If not, how will the app know where and how to find the user's IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users IP address is sent as part of the request header with all http requests.

you can get if from `request.remote_ip` in rails

see [Rails: Get Client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465476/rails-get-client-ip-address)

Comment: Hey Ian, thanks for the quick response. Is this a new method then that goes in the users_controller, or does it go in the User model?

Comment: the request object is already available in a rails application see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Comment: This is great. So seems like i should just be able to define a new method in my users_controller, and then display users in my index by calling that method. Thanks Ian!