# How do I pass the remote (users) IP from nginx to Rails hosted on google container engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ip-address, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running passenger on nginx and have a rails app server. I'm unable to get the user's remote IP.. how can I get the User's IP?

I use a `nginx.conf.erb` which I can modify if needed..

The problem (I think) arises in google container engine which creates a load balancer in front of my app.. making `request.remote_ip` only get a local kubernetes cluster-ip rather than the remote ip..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: Get Client IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465476/rails-get-client-ip-address)

Comment: @Jonathan nope -- this is specific to kubernetes and/or google container engine

Answer (score 0):

That should be pretty simple, infact you don't have to pass it from Nginx it always comes to rails as headers. You can access it as follows,

```
request.remote_ip
```

Comment: this gives me the load_balancer's ip on google container engine, not the user's ip