# How to get the IP address of my local machine in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ip-address

I am doing Rails development in Ubuntu 12.04LTS OS.

I want to capture my local IP address in a file, not the loopback 127.0.0.1, the one which I get using `ifconfig`.  Please suggest a solution.

Comment: you have to just use `request.remote_ip` ref [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887943/ip-address-in-rails

Comment: @Salil: That will always give 127.0.0.1 as o/p. But, I need the internet IP address which I get for 'ifconfig' command. Thanks.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14112955/128421 also.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [Socket::ip_address_list](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-ip_address_list).

```
Socket.ip_address_list #=> Array of AddrInfo
```

Comment: can you please suggest how we could get the second value from the array that we get by using "Socket.ip_address_list #=> Array of AddrInfo". I am not getting that in normal way. Thanks

Comment: Second is not always proper one. You might have number of different interfaces and loopbacks. You can use following code to reject all "local" addresses and expose first external `Socket.ip_address_list.find {|a| a.ipv4? ? !(a.ipv4_private? || a.ipv4_loopback?)  :  !(a.ipv6_sitelocal? || a.ipv6_linklocal? || a.ipv6_loopback?) }`

Comment: What exactly is not working? And please provide your AddrInfo array. May be your machine does not own remote ip, sou you need to drop ipv4_private? and ipv6_sitelocal? from conditions in order to get local subnet ip.

Comment: OP asks for local IP (assuming IPv4), so:
`puts Socket.ip_address_list.find { |a| a.ipv4_private? && !a.ipv4_loopback? }.ip_address`

Answer (score 3):

This is my first way:

```
require 'socket' 
    def local_ip
  orig, Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup, true  # turn off reverse DNS resolution temporarily

  UDPSocket.open do |s|
    s.connect '64.233.187.99', 1
    s.addr.last
  end
ensure
  Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = orig
end

# irb:0> local_ip
# => "192.168.0.127"
```

This is my second way, which is not recommended:

```
require 'socket'
 Socket::getaddrinfo(Socket.gethostname,”echo”,Socket::AF_INET)[0][3]
```

The third way:

```
 UDPSocket.open {|s| s.connect('64.233.187.99', 1); s.addr.last }
```

And a fourth way:

```
Use Socket#ip_address_list

Socket.ip_address_list #=> Array of AddrInfo
```

Comment: can you please suggest how we could get the second value from the array that we get by using "Socket.ip_address_list #=> Array of AddrInfo". I am not getting that in normal way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Write below method

```
def self.local_ip
    orig, Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup, true
    UDPSocket.open do |s|
      s.connect '64.233.187.99', 1
      s.addr.last
    end
    ensure
      Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = orig
 end
```

and then call local_ip method, you will get ip address of your machine.

```
Eg: ip_address= local_ip
```