# How to get my machine's IP address from Ruby without leveraging from other IP address?

Tags: ruby, sockets, ip

I have searched everywhere but their solution requires some form of IP address.
Here are the solutions i have found.

```
    require 'socket'
#METHOD 1
    ip = IPSocket.getaddress(Socket.gethostname)
    puts ip 

#METHOD 2
    host = Socket.gethostname
    puts host

#METHOD 3(uses Google's address)
    ip = UDPSocket.open {|s| s.connect("64.233.187.99", 1); s.addr.last}
    puts ip

#METHOD 4(uses gateway address)
    def local_ip
      orig, Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup, true  # turn off reverse DNS resolution temporarily

      UDPSocket.open do |s|
        s.connect '192.168.1.1', 1
        s.addr.last
      end
    ensure
      Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = orig
    end

    ip=local_ip
    puts ip
```

All of them require IP address of someone. Is there a solution that does not use someone else's IP address? Preferably, platform independent.

Comment: What "IP address of someone" does the first one require? Also, who said that gateways are always at 192.168.1.1

Comment: This http://rubygems.org/gems/system-getifaddrs might help.

Comment: Local or global? (eg. 192.168.1.23 or 75.75.75.64)?

Comment: what wrong with method 1?

Comment: @EvgeniyRyzhkov: Verbatim from the docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html): "*... If you want to know the current machine’s IP address, you may want to use gethostbyname(gethostname()). This operation assumes that there is a valid address-to-host mapping for the host, and the assumption does not always hold.*". Please note the **last seven words**.

Comment: UDPSocket.connect(someone else's IP) doesn't actually connect, UDP being famously connectionless.  So the use of someone else's IP, while inelegant, is functionally harmless.  Well, elegance has a value, but using 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1, as suggested by some answers at https://superuser.com/questions/698244/ip-address-that-is-the-equivalent-of-dev-null, doesn't work here.

Answer (score 50):

Isn't the solution you are looking for just:

```rb
require 'socket'

addr_infos = Socket.ip_address_list
```

Since a machine can have multiple interfaces and multiple IP Addresses, this method returns an array of [Addrinfo](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Addrinfo.html).

You can fetch the exact IP addresses like this:

```rb
addr_infos.each do |addr_info|
  puts addr_info.ip_address
end
```

You can further filter the list by rejecting loopback and private addresses, as they are usually not what you're interested in, like so:

```rb
addr_infos.reject( &:ipv4_loopback? )
          .reject( &:ipv6_loopback? )
          .reject( &:ipv4_private? )
```

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7's Socket doesn't have ip_address_list().  I too wish I didn't have to care.

Comment: @MartinDorey :D My condolences. But you can still use [Eugene Rourke's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14113251/894209).

Answer (score 32):

This is what I've been using in production for years:

```
require 'socket'
ip = Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4_private?}
ip.ip_address
```

Works great; tested on aws and classical hosting

Comment: appears it uses getifaddrs under the covers, FWIW.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7809076/32453 if you are looking for a public ipv4

Answer (score 16):

```
require 'socket'
Socket::getaddrinfo(Socket.gethostname,"echo",Socket::AF_INET)[0][3]
```

quite like method 1, actually

Comment: Please see my comment on the OP, regarding the use of `gethostname()`.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no such thing as a default ip-interface to a host (there does not need to be any ip-interface at all actually) all assumptions regarding nameing are vague, do not necessarily hold.

The value returned by `gethostname()` can be defined independently to any ip-setup, so it does not need to reflect a valid host in terms of a hostname which could be resolved to any ip-address.

From the POSIX system's API's view the only reliabe function to test for the availablily of (ip-)interfaces is the function `getifaddrs()`, which returns a list of all interfaces along with their parameters.

As it looks as if Ruby's current Socket lib does not provide an interface to it, [this (http://rubygems.org/gems/system-getifaddrs)](http://rubygems.org/gems/system-getifaddrs) gem based approach does seem to be the only way to go.

Comment: Socket.ip_address_list seems to use getifaddrs (though it might be recent since this answer was posted) FWIW.

Comment: Actually, a routing table can, and often does, specify a default interface.

Answer (score 0):

parse the output of the `ip` command?

from https://gist.github.com/henriquemenezes/a99f13da957515023e78aea30d6c0a48

```
gw = `ip route show`[/default.*/][/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/]
```

or parse the output of the `ipconfig` command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632929/32453

Comment: Won't that give you the ip address of the gateway for the default interface, not the ip address of the default interface?

Comment: man, what did you paste? This is the default GW, and if you have multiple default GW you need to check the one with lowest metric