# Ruby UDPSocket return Ipv6 address if runs on windows 2008 (non R2)

Tags: ruby, windows-server-2008, jruby

I need to get using Ruby the local-IPv4 address of remote machines through stateless connection. Running this UDPSocket call on Windows 2008(non R2):

```
 UDPSocket.open do |s|
    s.connect remote_machine_name, 1
    puts s.addr.last
 end
```

always returns the IPv6 address even though IPv6 is disabled.
Running on other windows platforms seems to be OK, any ideas why this fail on w2k8? any alternatives?

related link:
[How to get my machine's IP address from Ruby without leveraging from other IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112955/how-to-get-my-machines-ip-address-from-ruby-without-leveraging-from-other-ip-ad)